How to reload prometheus config without restarting?
How to reload prometheus config changes without restarting prometheus process.

To do this, you have to first start your Prometheus process with --web.enable-lifecycle flag. After starting with this flag, then you can hit the below URL every time you want to reload your config changes.
curl -X POST <your_prometheus_server_url>:<port>/-/reload
Related documentation here.

Thanks for mentioning the documentation!

kill -HUP  pid_of_prometheus


ref:
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#configuration
A configuration reload is triggered by

sending a SIGHUP to the Prometheus process or
sending a HTTP POST request to the /-/reload endpoint
(when the --web.enable-lifecycle flag is enabled).

